# Force Auto-Parallelization VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2012

Assume that /QPar is set, and for the following code:

```
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
for(int i = 0; i < u; i++)
{
   SomeExpensiveCall();
}
```

My u is small (~50), and SomeExpensiveCall takes ~1 second. The code doesn't appear to be getting parallelized (I commented out the hint and there was no change). Is there any way I can force the compiler to parallelize this?

Something I just thought of - would this have anything to do with the fact that the project containing the above code is in a static library that is linked into a CLI/C++ DLL that does not (and cannot) have /QPar?

Thanks

Comment: /Qpar-report:2 ought to tell you what's happening. Likely it doesn't want to parallel the function call due to potential side-effects.

Comment: Thank you - it turns out that I had several issues, namely error codes 500, 504 and 1000. I fixed 1000 by adding #pragma loop(ivdep), and 500/504 were fixed by replacing std::vectors with c++ arrays. I realized a 30%+ increase in performance of my code due to this. If you want to submit your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Qpar-report:2 ought to tell you what's happening. Likely it doesn't want to parallel the function call due to potential side-effects.